# GIT: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

We are getting following error when trying to clone using SSH URL:

```
$ git clone git@host:repository.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
```

We use GitLab on premise and use SSH URL to clone repositories. Yesterday all users and Jenkins reported issues cloning, pulling and pushing code to repositories. We figured out soon that HTTPS protocol works as expected and this issue was narrowed down to everyone using SSH URL.

Here are some things that we tried to get more details but to no help, except that we see after auth it fails with exit status 254 or 1 randomly:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git clone git@host:repository.git

GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git clone git@host:repository.git
```

Snippet of output from above commands

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to host ([a.y.x.b]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env GIT_PROTOCOL = version=2
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'repository.git'
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This
Transferred: sent 2352, received 2984 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 22560.7, received 28622.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: Try running `ssh git@host 'echo hello'` and see if it prints anything besides the "hello".

Comment: As a debugging step : running a plain `ssh git@host` can also help highlighting some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Check what are the supported shells

```
cat /etc/shells
```

In our case git user had shell disabled and the image below was showing /sbin/nologin

stopped the gitlab instance

```
gitlab-ctl stop
```

Update shell for git user (you can use any of the below command)

```
usermod -s which git-shell git
usermod -s /bin/sh git
```

Reconfigure GitLab

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigured
```

Restart GitLab Service

```
gitlab-ctl restart
```

Finally verify /sbin/nologin has changed to /bin/sh for git user as shown in image below

```
vi /etc/passwd | grep git
```

[image]

Comment: `/bin/sh` may not be the shell you'd like to use here. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell

Comment: We ran the following command, and I am told "which git-shell" maps to /bin/sh: usermod -s which git-shell git

Comment: With the setup you have, anyone who has `git@host` access can now run any command as user `git`. For instance, `ssh git@host echo test` will print `test`. This *might* be OK, depending on how much you trust your users. That's why I said *may not be*. It's just a note.